# Deleting a dynamic dropdown in excel using vba

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am populating a dynamic dropdown in excel. When my value is Digital I populate some values in adjacent cell and when it is other value it should delete that dropdown and disable the cell.

Can someone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address Like "*A*" And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Target.Value) Then
            With Target.Offset(0, 1)
                .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="Item1, Item2"
                .Value = "Item1"
                .Locked = False
            End With
        Else
            With Target.Offset(0, 1)
                .Validation.Delete
                .Value = ""
                .Locked = True
            End With
        End If
    End If

    End Sub
```